# Xamarin VS2022 - Error on Deploying to Device

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

Any suggestions/ideas appreciated!

After successfully starting/restarting Mac and VS2022; Pairing to Mac; and running debug on physical device (physically connected to mac). Getting this error quite frequently (constantly).

have rebooted the Mac and restarted VS, cleaned solution, removed bin/obj. Running most up to date versions (stable releases) of Xamarin, MacOS, Xcode, VS2022 etc.

[xma]: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Broker...
warning : [xma]: The underlying client has been disconnected by the remote host
warning : [xma]: An error occurred on the underlying client while executing an operation. Details: The client  has been disconnected while trying to perform the connection
warning : [xma]: There was an error while trying to connect the client build2a1eff0cc622e75ed405b9ae210073ce49bb7c09261084a1788896f1e1a4e3fb22400amit to the Server.
warning : The client  has been disconnected while trying to perform the connection
warning :    at System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl.d__28.MoveNext() in C:\a\1\s\src\Client\Sdk\MqttClientImpl.cs:line 111
warning : --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
warning :    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
warning :    at System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl.d__28.MoveNext() in C:\a\1\s\src\Client\Sdk\MqttClientImpl.cs:line 139
warning : --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
warning :    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
warning :    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
warning :    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingConnection.d__21.MoveNext() in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingConnection.cs:line 64
warning : [xma]: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Broker...
error : MessagingException: An error occurred while executing the operation and the connection could not be reestablished
error : ClientDisconnectedException: The client build2a1eff0cc622e75ed405b9ae210073ce49bb7c09261084a1788896f1e1a4e3fb22400amit has been disconnected while waiting a post response to topic xvs/build/execute-task/AstromechControl.iOS/2a1eff0002fMTouch

Comment: Please check this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting)

Comment: Thanks! Greatly appreciated. I didn't see the deletion of files off the mac (towards the bottom of document) that should help. Will not get to try till later, but will report back!

Comment: Wish you success.